# why memory address of sum(&sum) is necessary pass to pthread_exit function to get correct output from below pthread program?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I don't understand what  **pthread_exit(&sum)** function do below code ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void *
sum_runner(void *arg)
{

    int *limit_ptr = (int *) arg;
    int limit = *limit_ptr;

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i; i <= limit; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    printf("sum is for thread %lu is %d : \n", pthread_self(), sum);
    pthread_exit(&sum);

}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("You entered only number %s : \n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    int nOfThreads = argc - 1;
    int i;
    int limit[nOfThreads];

    printf("limit  = %d \n", nOfThreads);
    for (i = 0; i < nOfThreads; i++) {

        limit[i] = atoll(argv[i + 1]);
        printf("%d, %p\n", limit[i], &limit[i]);
        pthread_t tid[i];

        pthread_create((tid + i), NULL, sum_runner, (limit + i));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nOfThreads; i++) {
        pthread_t tid[i];

        pthread_join(*(tid + i), NULL);
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in pthread I know `pthread_exit()` function use to exit the from calling thread but I don't understand why `&sum` is necessary to pass to `pthread_exit` function to get the correct output.

Comment: some proper indentation would help. You have variable scope issues, among others. `pthread_t tid[i];` creates a local array of `pthread_t` types `i` big that is only visible inside the `for` loop where it's declared _for that specific iteration_. So this creates arrays of size 0, 1, ,, `nOfThreads-1`. When `i` is zero, you have no `pthread_t`s in your array, and so you're calling `pthread_create` on an object that doesn't exist, which is surely undefined behavior. Furthermore, the `pthread_t`s in your second `for` loop are not the same as those in the first, I'd guess calling `pthread_join`

Comment: on a thread that hasn't been created yet is also UB. You need to move your array of `pthread_t`s outside of the loops, `pthread_t tid[nOfThreads];` up where `int limit[nOfThreads];` is.

Comment: It is not necessary and using `&sum` because `sum` is function scope (i.e. _not_ global) is wrong because the main task could _not_ dereference it. You don't actually do anything in `main` with the code that is returned anyway.

Comment: even in the context of your local `tid` arrays, you're accessing them out of bounds every iteration of the loop. For an array with size `n`, you can access it from 0 to `n-1`. `array[n]` is out of bounds. This is what you're doing by passing `tid + i` to `pthread_create` and `pthread_join`. Accessing an array out of bounds invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: It isn't necessary. What happens if you don't pass &sum?

Comment: @CraigEstey: The scope isn't what makes it invalid to reference it from the main thread; that's no problem, and accessing things outside of their scope is one of the main purposes of pointers. The problem is that it's undefined to access it after its lifetime has ended, which is the case after you call `pthread_exit`.

Comment: @user253751, if you call `pthread_exit()` then you have to pass *some* argument.  If you know that the program will not use whatever the thread emits anyway, then the natural thing to do would be to pass `NULL`.  Note also that you could also just `return` the result from the thread function.  `pthread_exit()` has the most relevance for allowing other functions called by the thread function to cause the thread to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out the problem. It was **pthread_t tid[i];** . It should be declared in the global scope instead of the loop scope. In my case, as it is in loop scope pthread_join() function doesn't keep the main thread(main function) wait until all the created threads finish its execution.
final code should be as below,

```
**pthread_t tid[i];**

for (i = 0; i < nOfThreads; i++) {

    limit[i] = atoll(argv[i + 1]);
    printf("%d, %p\n", limit[i], &limit[i]);
    pthread_create((tid + i), NULL, sum_runner, (limit + i));
}

for (i = 0; i < nOfThreads; i++) {

    pthread_join(*(tid + i), NULL);
}
```